# Timer Schedule - Java

Tags: java, swing, timer, compiler-errors, schedule

```
new java.util.Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(timeleft(), 0, 1000);
```

This is my code for a method `timeleft()` that i want to happen every second.
My class is called Timer. 
Not sure why I'm getting an error.

---

It says "void type not allowed here" when I hover over the line.
I am using a JFrame for a GUI and put this inside an event when I press a button along with a timer that counts down from whatever number you enter in a text field.

Comment: _an error_ What error?

Comment: What's your error...

Comment: In your mind, what does `timeleft()` mean when you write it inside another method?

Comment: Sorry. It says "void type not allowed here" when I hover over the line.

Comment: If you had to guess, what would you say that means?

Comment: The method I am trying to use is a void. I'm assuming it means I can't use a void method for that value. I'm not sure.

Comment: `"Sorry. It says "void type not allowed here" when I hover over the line."` -- this is **critical** information and should not be buried in a comment, but rather should be part of your question. I've edited your question and have included the information, but for future reference, please make sure to try to ask as complete a question as possible.

Comment: I see. I apologize for this I'm new to this website and Java in general.

Comment: Not a problem, but since you are new here you will want to go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions. Asking questions is a learned skill, and with practice and effort yours will likely improve.

Answer (score 2):

You state:

> I am using a JFrame for a GUI and put this inside an event when I press a button along with a timer that counts down from whatever number you enter in a text field.

I'm going to recommend that you consider throwing out the code that you're asking your question on, to completely re-think your approach.

If you want to create and run a repeated event in a Swing GUI, don't use a java.util.Timer as you're doing, since you can easily run into serious Swing threading issues. Instead use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), a Timer that works well with Swing, since all code in the Timer's ActionListener is guaranteed to run on the Swing event thread.

To start you out, your code could look something like:

```
int timerDelay = 1000; // 1000 msecs or 1 second
Timer timer = new Timer(timerDelay, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
       // code that needs to be repeated goes here
    }

});
timer.setInitialDelay(0);
timer.start();
```

Although for a count-down timer, I'm not sure that I'd set the initial delay to 0. Instead, I'd let it wait the period.

Comment: I am very confused. Would it help if I sent my code? I am using NetBeans to make my GUI and I create events by right clicking on buttons on my GUI screen. I put that in one of the event methods and got tons of errors. This was when I hovered over the creation of timer: <anonymous Timer$4> is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener

Comment: @Aria: one of the reasons I don't like NetBeans's code generation since it shields newbies from having to know how the Swing library works, and so they don't understand it. But regardless, if you're seeing problems, then yes post code with any and all error messages. But also, never post code you see on this site blindly into your program. Instead, borrow the ideas, but create your own code. Also, when you get error messages, look at them critically since they will usually tell you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.util.TimerTask-java.util.Date-long-), the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method accepts a `TimerTask` as a first argument. You seem to be trying to pass the result of a method, named `timeleft()`, with a `void` return type.

If you need to execute some code at a fixed rate, then you need to create a [`TimerTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) object with an appropriate `run` implementation and pass that to `scheduleAtFixedRate`.